# (XSLT) why Saxon-HE 9.8 processor slower then dotNet processor in my case?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, saxon

(NOTE: this post has been edited largely via reply suggestion)
I am currently run the almost the same xslt in dotNet processer and Saxon-HE 9.8 processer , But I found that Saxon(2.2 second) is much slower then dotNet(0.03 second).  So how can I fixed it?  here's my 【simplified】 xml sample, Just Copy `<A>`~`<Z>` and repeatedly paste like 50 times, and I think is only about 10kb in size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="OutputFile.xslt"?>
  <Header>
      <A><![CDATA[NOTHING]]></A>
      <B><![CDATA[NOTHING]]></B>
      <C><![CDATA[NOTHING]]></C>
    <X>_R_testXR12</X>
    <Y>_R_testYR12</Y>
    <Z>_R_testZR12</Z>
  </Header>
```

here are my code on both:

Saxon C#

```
var processor = new Processor();
var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
var executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xslt.FullName));
var transformer = executable.Load30();
var serializer = new Serializer();

FileStream outStream = new FileStream(output.ToString(), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
serializer.SetOutputStream(outStream);

using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
{

    /*timer start*/
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    transformer.ApplyTemplates(inputStream, serializer);
    /*timer end*/
    watch.Stop(); var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs); Console.Read();
    outStream.Close();
}
```

Saxon XSLT

```
    <!--  Saxon  in xslt-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="NodesExtraCRI" select="/Header/*[( starts-with(text(), '_R_testZR'))]"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select = "$NodesExtraCRI">
          <xsl:sort select = "text()" data-type = "number" order = "ascending"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.NET C#

```
// Enable XSLT debugging.  
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

// Compile the style sheet.  
xslt.Load(stylesheet);

// Execute the XSLT transform. 
/*timer start*/
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Append);
xslt.Transform(sourceFile, null, outputStream);
/*timer end*/
watch.Stop(); var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs); Console.Read();
```

.NET XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="NodesExtraCRI" select="/Header/*[( starts-with(text(), '_R_testZR'))]"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select = "$NodesExtraCRI">
        <xsl:sort select = "text()" data-type = "number" order = "ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the "dotNet" processor (XslCompiledTransform, XslTransform, XmlPrime)? And what have you measured exactly how? Share the code or the method that gave those timings.

Comment: Thx, I edited it

Comment: In general you have to be aware that Saxon 9 HE for .NET and Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform have very different architectures, Saxon is developed as a Java application and then cross-compiled with IKVM to .NET, having to carry around the various assemblies that provide the Java based run-time structure on .NET, XslCompiledTransform on the other hand is a compiler from XSLT 1 to .NET's CIL, so it terms of pure run-time performance XslCompiledTransform is probably always ahead of Saxon .NET HE. Saxon EE might perform better than HE as it includes byte code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the extreme differences you say you get but I have not been able to do that.

As I couldn't understand what the provided stylesheet is supposed to do, in particular the `xsl:sort` with `data-type = "number"` on elements selected earlier to start with `_R_testZR` (i.e. letters and not digits) seems meaningless, I first wrote some stylesheet to create some sample data to be sorted.

Then I created a stylesheet to sort the generated sample data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(., 'test_Z')]">
                <xsl:sort select="@pos" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That stylesheet I run first from the command line with Saxon 9.8.0.7 HE Java and .NET and the `-t -repeat` options, to get some insight whether it really takes seconds. However, the Java version reported

> Average execution time over last 11 runs: 48.161523ms

and the .NET version

> Average execution time over last 11 runs: 79.13861ms

So the .NET version is (as known) considerably slower than the Java version, but it takes millseconds and not seconds, at least on my machine.

Furthermore I then wrote some C# console application code in Visual Studio 2017 to execute the same stylesheet against the same sample, using code like

```
    static void RunSaxon(string xmlUrl, string xslUrl, string outputFile)
    {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xslUrl)).Load30();

        using (Stream resultStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
        {
            using (Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(xmlUrl))
            {
                xslt30Transformer.ApplyTemplates(inputStream, processor.NewSerializer(resultStream));
            }
        }
    }
```

and used the [Profiler in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling) to profile that code, and the results show considerable amounts of CPU usage do not even result from the `ApplyTemplates()` call, but rather the main usage is by the `Compile` method (nearly 64 %) followed by the `new Processor()` constructor (nearly 28.5 %):

```
Function Name   Total CPU (ms)  Total CPU (%)   Self CPU (ms)   Self CPU (%)    Module
Saxon98HEPerfTest.exe (PID: 17768)  718 100,00 %    718 100,00 %    Saxon98HEPerfTest.exe
  Saxon98HEPerfTest.Program::Main   680 94,71 % 0   0,00 %  Saxon98HEPerfTest.exe
  Saxon98HEPerfTest.Program::RunSaxon   677 94,29 % 0   0,00 %  Saxon98HEPerfTest.exe
  [External Call] Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler::Compile   458 63,79 % 458 63,79 % Multiple modules
  [External Call] Saxon.Api.Processor::.ctor    204 28,41 % 204 28,41 % Multiple modules
  [External Call] Saxon.Api.Processor::NewXsltCompiler  5   0,70 %  5   0,70 %  Multiple modules
```

Some more detailed data I got by setting breakpoints in the RunSaxon method:

```
Function Name   Total CPU (ms)  Total CPU (%)   Self CPU (ms)   Self CPU (%)    Module
Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler::Compile 683 61,20 % 683 61,20 % Multiple modules
Saxon.Api.Processor::.ctor  214 19,18 % 214 19,18 % Multiple modules
Saxon.Api.Xslt30Transformer::ApplyTemplates 181 16,22 % 181 16,22 % Multiple modules
Saxon.Api.Processor::NewXsltCompiler    5   0,45 %  5   0,45 %  Multiple modules
Saxon.Api.XsltExecutable::Load30    3   0,27 %  3   0,27 %  Multiple modules
Saxon.Api.Processor::NewSerializer  1   0,09 %  1   0,09 %  Multiple modules
System.IO.File.OpenWrite(System.String)$##60017A3   1   0,09 %  1   0,09 %  Multiple modules
```

I also tried to use a Stopwatch to measure the `ApplyTemplates()` call, as you tried:

```
    static void MeasureSaxon(string xmlUrl, string xslUrl, string outputFile)
    {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xslUrl)).Load30();

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        using (Stream resultStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
        {
            using (Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(xmlUrl))
            {            
                watch.Start();
                xslt30Transformer.ApplyTemplates(inputStream, processor.NewSerializer(resultStream));
                watch.Stop();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

the results I get are about 165 ms. XslCompiledTransform is way faster admittedly, with about 32 ms, measured with

```
    private static void RunXslCompiledTransform(string xmlUrl, string xslUrl, string outputFile)
    {
        XslCompiledTransform processor = new XslCompiledTransform();
        processor.Load(xslUrl);

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        processor.Transform(xmlUrl, outputFile);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

but I don't get such extreme differences as you seem to have experienced.

Here is the stylesheet (needs Saxon PE or EE due to `random-number-generator()` use) that generates the sample data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="seed" as="xs:dateTime" select="current-dateTime()"/>

    <xsl:param name="items" as="xs:integer" select="5000"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="random-number-generator($seed)?permute(1 to $items)">
                <A>...</A>
                <B>...</B>
                <C>...</C>
                <X>test_Y</X>
                <Y>test_Y</Y>
                <Z pos="{.}">test_Z_{format-number(., '0000')}</Z>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As the stylesheet to generate the sample data requires Saxon PE or EE, I have uploaded the generated sample input to https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/test2018012001Input5000.xml.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET version of Saxon is often 3-5 times slower than the Java version, and despite strenuous efforts, we don't actually know why. At one time it was only 25% slower.

I suspect that the big difference you're seeing here is primarily initialization cost. Although your timer is only measuring the transformation time (including source document parsing and serialization but not stylesheet compilation), you're only running the transformation once and it would be interesting to see whether the numbers are different if you run it say 20 times and take an average.

You haven't said what the source document size is, but unless it's hundreds of megabytes, the time of 2.2s here seems quite excessive, and it's definitely worth looking for an explanation.

I note that the body of the `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">` loop doesn't depend on the context item, so there's scope for a "loop lifting" optimization here that only executes the body once and then replicates the result. Saxon-HE doesn't attempt such optimizations, but Saxon-EE does, and it's quite possible that the Microsoft processor does too. But that's not enough to account for this difference.

So, I would suggest the following experiments to gather more insight:

(a) run the transform repeatedly from the C# level to get an average timing.

(b) eliminate the possibility of loop-lifting optimization by doing something in the body of the loop that means the results are different each time

(c) see how the transformation time varies with source document size

(d) do some profiling to see where the hotspots are.

Comment: I make some change to test via your suggestion and add more information, and I think the document size doesn't matter because I tested a 10-kb-sized XML, u can take a look at my EDITED post, and I think it really worth for an explanation too, since Sir you're developer it would be great if you try the sample, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to run the code snippets you provided.

Here are my results:

Saxon .Net version: 59 ms (Compile time 28 ms, Runtime 31 ms)

.Net Version: 3 ms

We know that Saxon is slower on .NET, but I am not seeing the 2-3 seconds speed reported.